# Golden Ratio Fibonacci Hell

Tags: fibonacci

In one of my **java** programs I am trying to read a number and then use the golden ratio (1.618034) to find the next smallest fibonacci number its index. For example, if I enter `100000` I should get back "the smallest fibonacci number which is greater than 100000 is the 26th and its value is 121393".

The program should also calculate a fibonacci number by index (`case 1` in the code below) which I have coded so far, but I can't figure out how to solve the problem described above (`case 2`). I have a horrible teacher and I don't really understand what I need to do. I am not asking for the code, just kind of a step by step what I should do for `case 2`. I can not use recursion. Thank you for any help. I seriously suck at wrapping my head around this.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Fibonacci {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("This is a Fibonacci sequence generator");
    System.out.println("Choose what you would like to do");
    System.out.println("1. Find the nth Fibonacci number");
    System.out.println("2. Find the smallest Fibonacci number that exceeds user given value");
    System.out.println("3. Find the two Fibonacci numbers whose ratio is close enough to the golden number");

    System.out.print("Enter your choice: ");
    int choice = scan.nextInt();
    int xPre = 0;
    int xCurr = 1;
    int xNew = 0;

    switch (choice)
    {
        case 1:
            System.out.print("Enter the target index to generate (>1): ");
            int index = scan.nextInt();

            for (int i = 2; i <= index; i++)
            {
                xNew = xPre + xCurr;
                xPre = xCurr;
                xCurr = xNew;
            }
            System.out.println("The " + index + "th number Fibonacci number is " + xNew);
                break;
        case 2:
            System.out.print("Enter the target value (>1): ");
            int value = scan.nextInt();

    }
}
}
```

Comment: You can put it in a `while` loop and calculating the Fibonacci number until it's bigger than `value`.

Comment: Like i said I really don't understand how to do this entire calculation. I am trying my best, but I know with a  while loop you have the condition and statement, but what should i put for the statement calculation?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should understand what this golden ration story is all about. The point is, Fibonacci numbers can be calced recursively, but there's also a formula for the nth Fibonacci number:

φ(n) = [φ^n - (-φ)^(-n)]/√5

where φ = (√5 + 1)/2 is the Golden Ratio (approximately 1.61803). Now, |(-φ)^(-1)| < 1 which means that you can calc φ(n) as the closest integer to φ^n/√5 (unless n = 1).

So, calc √5, calc φ, then learn how to get an integer closest to the value of a real variable and then calc φ(n) using the φ^n/√5 formula (or just use the "main" [φ^n - (-φ)^(-n)]/√5 formula) in a loop and in that loop compare φ(n) with the number that user input. When φ(n) exceeds the user's number, remember n and φ(n).